# How to iterate xml nodes using java code

Tags: java, xml

I Should check whether the `<LineItem>` contains `<Tender>`( this `<Tender>` can be in any of the `<LineItem>`, Here in this XML its in last `<LineItem>`). If `<Tender>` is present, I should again begin the loop from first to check whether the `<LineItem>` contains `<Return>`.

The xml is as follow:

```
<Transaction>
    <LineItem>
        <Return></Return>
    </LineItem>
    <LineItem>
        <Return></Return>
    </LineItem>
    <LineItem>
        <Return></Return>
    </LineItem>
    <LineItem>
        <Return></Return>
    </LineItem>
    <LineItem>
        <Tender></Tender>
    </LineItem>
</Transaction>
```

How to iterate through XML and check `<Tender>`, and again how to iterate from beginning to check `<Return>`?

I have Implemented as (just code snippet i have provided, as it is huge)

```
//Tender Type
    Lineitems = retailChildren.item(j).getChildNodes();
    for(int i2=0;i2<Lineitems.getLength();i2++)
    {
        if(Lineitems.item(i2).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Tender")){
            System.out.println("Inside Tender");
            //start
            NodeList TenderId=Lineitems.item(i2).getChildNodes();
            TenderId=Lineitems.item(i2).getChildNodes();
            for(int i4=0;i4<TenderId.getLength();i4++){
                if(TenderId.item(i4).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("TenderID")){
                    System.out.println("Inside Tender ID");
                    String TenderID=TenderId.item(i4).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    System.out
                    .println(TenderID);
                    NodeList SaleType=TenderId.item(i2).getChildNodes();
                    //SaleType=TenderId.item(i2).getChildNodes();
                    for(int i3=0;i3<SaleType.getLength();i3++){
                        if(SaleType.item(i3).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("bby:SaleTenderType")){
                            System.out.println("Inside Sale Tender Type");
                            String eCommValue=SaleType.item(i3).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                            if(eCommValue.equalsIgnoreCase("Magento")){
                                System.out.println("Inside Magento");

                                Lineitems = retailChildren.item(j).getChildNodes();
                                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < Lineitems.getLength(); i1++) {
                                    if(Lineitems.item(i1).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Return")){
                                        //Do method
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // If <Tender> is not present, it should come here
        else
        {
            Lineitems = retailChildren.item(j).getChildNodes();
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < Lineitems.getLength(); i1++) {
                if(Lineitems.item(i1).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Return")){
                    //do method
                }
            }

        }//End for for tender type

    }
```

Comment: @JPMoresmau-- code included.I am using DOM parser

Comment: do you just want a list of `tender` and a list of `return` ?

Comment: I think you'll likely find that this is much easier to solve with xpath.

Comment: @KennethClark- First I want to check whether `<Tender>` is there.. If present, I should read the `<Return>`

Comment: So if tender exist's in transaction then read all the return nodes ?

Comment: @KennethClark yes.. exactly

Answer (score 1):

You can get the node from the xml using XPATH

***XPath***, the XML Path Language, is a query language for selecting nodes from an XML document. In addition, XPath may be used to compute values (e.g., strings, numbers, or Boolean values) from the content of an XML document. [What is Xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

Your XPath expression will be

```
/Transaction/LineItem/Return
boolean(/Transaction/LineItem/Tender)
```

I have made an assumption that you have the xml as string so you will need the following idea

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();    
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
Document document = builder.parse(inputSource);
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
```

You will first have to check if the node is present by

```
Boolean hasTender = (Boolean) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.BOOLEAN);
```

the simply look for the `Return` nodes

```
  XPathExpression exprResult = xpath.compile("/Transaction/LineItem/Return");
  NodeList nl = (NodeList) exprResult.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Now it will be simply loop through each node

```
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
{
  System.out.println(nl.item(i).getNodeName());
}
```

in a nutshell the following code .. keep in mind you want to break this into methods for reuse.

**Controller test**

```
public class Controller {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException, IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {

    String xml ="<Transaction>\n" +
            "    <LineItem>\n" +
            "        <Return></Return>\n" +
            "    </LineItem>\n" +
            "    <LineItem>\n" +
            "        <Return></Return>\n" +
            "    </LineItem>\n" +
            "    <LineItem>\n" +
            "        <Return></Return>\n" +
            "    </LineItem>\n" +
            "    <LineItem>\n" +
            "        <Return></Return>\n" +
            "    </LineItem>\n" +
            "    <LineItem>\n" +
            "        <Tender></Tender>\n" +
            "    </LineItem>\n" +
            "</Transaction>";

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    Document document = builder.parse(inputSource);
    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("boolean(/Transaction/LineItem/Tender)");
    Boolean hasTender = (Boolean) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.BOOLEAN);
    if (hasTender)
    {
      XPathExpression exprResult = xpath.compile("/Transaction/LineItem/Return");
      NodeList nl = (NodeList) exprResult.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
      for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
      {
        System.out.println(nl.item(i).getNodeName());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it's substantially more detailed than my answer.

Comment: Thanks.. cant I iterate through for loops.??

Comment: iterating the for loop above is each `Return` node. So you can add you logic there

Answer (score 1):

Use XPath instead

```
XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath path = xpf.newXPath();
XPathExpression tenderExpr = path.compile("/Transaction//LineItem/Tender");
NodeList tenderNodes = (NodeList)tenderExpr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
if (tenderNodes.getLength() > 0) {
    // tender was found
} else {
    XPathExpression returnExpr = path.compile("/Transaction//LineItem/Return");
    NodeList returnNodes = (NodeList)returnExpr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    // returnNodes has all the elements you wanted, iterate that and see what you can see
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Because all of the classes used here have been part of the standard JavaSE toolkit since version 1.5.  I'd be very surprised if SAP would let you use `NodeList` but *not* `XPathFactory`

Comment: Thanks.. This will work. But I have to read each and every node inside `Tender` .. I have not provided complete code/ xml

Comment: The `NodeList` returned by `evaluate` is the same kind you used in your sample code -- it just contains only the nodes that match the path.  It just cuts down the work of finding things.  If you need to process each node inside it, you still can still `getChildNodes()`.  Or you might consider an additional set of `XPathExpressions` to find the other parts you care about more easily.  The possibilities are endless.